# Парсер для языка программирования

Tags: парсер

Мне необходимо написать парсер для языка программирования с досточно сложным синтаксисом. (Ориентиры: Ruby, Smalltalk). Необходимо разбирать операторы с различным приоритетом.

Как это сделать проще и удобнее? Скорость не так важна.

**UPD**:

Список фич синтаксиса, которые придётся разбирать:

- Необязательность скобок при вызове метода.
- Операторы с приоритетами (Приоритеты жёстко заданы заранее)
- Используются отступы для обозначения аргументов оператора, перенесённых на новую строку.

Пример кода, который необходимо распарсить: [здесь](https://gist.github.com/909680)

**UPD**: Книга дракона ещё не прочтена, но уже в пути.

**UPD**: Ещё вопрос, насколько это будет плохо, если мой парсер будет разбирать код лишь загрузив весь исходник в память? Для языка программирования это фатально?

Comment: Описание синтаксиса вашего языка есть? Примеры кода?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Выбор стоит - либо синтаксически управляемая трансляция (lex/yacc/bison/...), либо "ручками". Если есть время - попробуй оба варианта для небольшого подмножества языка, чтобы понять плюсы и минусы.

Парсинг Ruby делается с помощю синтаксически-управляемой трансляции (судя по исходникам). Теория этого неплохо описана у Ахо.

Из генераторов - пощупай ANTLR, сам не пробовал, но отзывы хорошие.

И ещё раз - без хорошей теоретической подготовки не обойтись, посмотри пару книг, того же Ахо, или Свердлов, или Мозговой.

Comment: Сейчас разбираюсь с ANTLR, похоже то что надо.

Answer (score 3):

Для успешного использования Lex, Bison и т.п. надо постоянно их использовать (как собственно и любой инструмент). Иначе, если через годик понадобиться что-либо изменить,
возникнут проблемы. Лично я использую C - 'ручками', но естественно после хотя бы
полуформального описания (для себя) синтаксиса.

Замечание по поводу отступов, если можно обойтись без них (например используя признак конца или продолжения оператора), то это удобнее при программировании. Вообще, на первый взгляд, такой код парсится за один проход.

Answer (score 1):

Ну что тут скажешь?
Чтобы проект компилера/интерпретатора был удобным для развития и просто изменения/правки, достаточно устроить классическую схему: Лексер -> Интерпретатор. А о том, как - в двух словах не расскажешь. RTFM, please. =)

Книги:

[Dragon Book: Компиляторы: принципы, технологии и инструменты.](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B:_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%8B,_%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%B8_%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B)

[Никлаус вирт: Построение компиляторов](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%82,_%D0%9D%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%83%D1%81)

Answer (score 1):

> UPD: Ещё вопрос, насколько это будет плохо, если мой парсер будет разбирать код лишь загрузив весь исходник в память? Для языка программирования это фатально?

Это не фатально, если вам не жалко памяти. Но нет никаких "за", чтобы загружать всё в память - ведь всё можно парсить потоком.

Comment: Мне значительно легче загрузить всё в память и сделать несколько проходов чем разбирать потоком.

Comment: Ответ сильно зависит от языка. Если он больше декларативный, чем императивный, то в память загружать неизбежность. Если можно исполнять "на лету", то лучше на лету. Несколько проходов это нехорошо, сделайте такие структуры данных, чтобы даже в памяти это было в один проход.

Answer (score 0):

Попроуйте [Bison](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/bison.htm) или [YACC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yacc) ([с примерами](http://yacc.solotony.com/))

Comment: Bison классический интструмент для такого. Но он очень стар, возможно появились другие, более удобные инструменты для этого? От одного взгляда на Ruby-parser становится страшно.

Comment: хм, Windows ещё старше :). Есть файлы для скачивания прошлогодние - значит, пордукт не так давно развивался как минимум

Comment: Я имею виду свежие идеи, а не свежесть версии.

Comment: я думал, нужно работающее и подходящее под формальные требования решение, а, оказывается, требуется "свежее", непонятно зачем, и непонятно, что в "старых" не устраивает.

Comment: Решение с помощью bison выглядит громоздко. Я надеялся на существование более удобных и человечных средств.

Comment: поапдэйтил яком, вроде тот попроще

Comment: но это для Вас не новость наверное

Comment: Мне кажется, проще решений нет. Зато раз разобравшись в компиляторакомпиляторе, потом очень быстро и надёжно будете развивать ваш проект

Comment: Flex/Bison - рабочая связка, опробована в боях, не подведет.